# Kafka messages received in [B@ format

Tags: apache-kafka, ibm-mq

I working a kafka connector to MQ, all installation is successful and messages from MQ are flowing to Kafka as expected. But the message I see in consumer console are in a different format which I dont get!
I'm putting plain text messages (ex - `Hi`) on MQ and getting them in this format on kafka - `[B@90e44060`

how to get plain text to plain text message?

Comment: Set the Kafka decoder to text, or defaults to byte array which is what you see.

Comment: Are you using IBM MQ?

Comment: @daniu - Thanks for the tip, I was able to make changes in the converting format. now getting messages in plain text.

Comment: @JoshMc - yes, IBM MQ.

Comment: I think you should provide a self answer to this and then accept it.  This would help anyone else that runs into the same problem you had.

Comment: Note that the answer would go in the "Your Answer" box below.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue in the `mq-source.properties` file set the following:

```
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
```